# How to get count data column in SQL server between different dates and each date has time range?

Tags: sql-server

Please, I need help for the correct sql syntax and how to do the following:

```
SELECT count(CreateDateTime) 
FROM tblINFO
WHERE  
 (CreateDateTime BETWEEN '2016-03-22 06:59:00' AND  '2016-03-22 14:59:00')
 OR
 (CreateDateTime BETWEEN '2016-04-14 06:59:00' AND  '2016-04-14 14:59:00')
```

I tried this Code but It calculated the count of (CreatedDateTime) only for those two days between the given times, But also I need to Calculate the count of the days that are between those two days between the same given times.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that if you described in your words what are you trying to achieve, it could have been more comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could interpret your question two ways. First one is that you want created date to be on either of those days, in which case you would do this;

```
SELECT count(CreatedDateTime) 
FROM tblINFO 
WHERE  
(createdDateTime BETWEEN '2015-03-22 06:59:00' AND  '2015-03-22 14:59:00')
OR
(createdDateTime BETWEEN '2015-04-14 06:59:00' AND  '2015-04-14 14:59:00')
```

The alternative would be that you want the created date to be between the start and end of those two dates, in which case you'd have this;

```
SELECT count(CreatedDateTime) 
FROM tblINFO 
WHERE  createdDateTime BETWEEN '2015-03-22 06:59:00' AND  '2015-04-14 14:59:00'
```

If you're after everything between those times on any day between 2015-03-22 and 2015-04-14 then you'll want something like this;

```
SELECT count(CreatedDateTime) 
FROM tblINFO 
WHERE  
(CONVERT(DATE,createdDateTime) BETWEEN '2015-03-22' AND  '2015-04-14')
AND
(CONVERT(TIME,createdDateTime) BETWEEN '06:59:00' AND  '14:59:00')
```

And if you want this to show you the count for all days but split by day, you'll want this;

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(Date,CreatedDateTime) Date
,count(CreatedDateTime) Volume
FROM tblINFO 
WHERE  
(CONVERT(DATE,createdDateTime) BETWEEN '2015-03-22' AND  '2015-04-14')
AND
(CONVERT(TIME,createdDateTime) BETWEEN '06:59:00' AND  '14:59:00')
GROUP BY CONVERT(Date,CreatedDateTime)
```

Comment: Thank you Rich for your reply but, I need the count of CreatedDateTime

Comment: That's what the code provides? The first code will find anything with a createddatetime on either of those two days between the given times. Could you be more descriptive with what you actually want? If you update the original question with some sample data and your expected output i'd be more than happy to revisit my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your Interest, For first Code, It calculated  the count of CreatedDateTime for those two days only between the given times, But I need to Calculate also, the count for the days that between those two days only between the same given times.

Comment: Then you want to use the DATEDIFF function; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189794.aspx if you want the number of days, or check out my latest edit if i've understood you correctly.

Comment: Thank you RICH  for all your assistance. The last 2 posted codes are working fine and my issue is solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If I Understood correctly your requirement, then this may help you

```
SELECT count(CreatedDateTime) 
FROM tblINFO 
WHERE (createdDateTime BETWEEN '2015/03/22 6:59:00' AND '2015/03/22 14:59:00' )
OR(createdDateTime BETWEEN '2015/04/14 6:59:00' AND '2015/04/14 14:59:00' )
OR(createdDateTime BETWEEN '2015/03/22 6:59:00' AND '2015/04/14 14:59:00' )
```

Comment: Thank you JaydipJ. I tried this Code before but It calculated the count of CreatedDateTime for those two days only between the given times, But I need to Calculate also, the count of the days that are between those two days between the same given times.

Comment: @Oracleman ok means you want to count of  betwenn range `2015/03/22 6:59:00' AND '2015/04/14 14:59:00'` as well right??